# How do you make foreign key as NOT NULL in EF Core migrations with Data Annotations?

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using ASP.NET Core and EF Core and I have the two following parent and child classes. Each gift card can have many transactions:

```
public class GiftCard
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BarCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
    public List<Transaction.Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public decimal TransactionAmount { get; set; }
    public TransactionType TransactionType { get; set; }
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
    public GiftCard.GiftCard GiftCard { get; set; }
}
```

Based on what I read, this is the way to do it, by having navigation property on the parent and reference navigation in child. When I add my migrations and update the database using the command line, everything seemed ok in the database except that the GiftCardId foreign key in the Transactions table is nullable. I want to make sure this is NOT NULL. Am I missing a Data Annotation attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the following property on your `Transaction` entity, and it should be resolved.

`public int GiftCardId { get; set; }`

What is happening with your definition is that a shadow property is being created and EF's Change Tracker is maintaining the relationships.

See [here](http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#no-foreign-key-property).

Comment: the page doesn't exist In the hyperlink you gave

Comment: [Required] attribute